# Submit data from Dialog to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I have a View from which a button call a dialog Bootstrap.
Inside this dialog I render this view:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new { @class = "form-control", id="form-create"  }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "wrapperViews" }))
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
<hr />
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div id="divParamType" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.PhaseID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.PhaseID,
                new SelectList(Model.Phases, "Value", "Text"), "", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Phase" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.PhaseID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.ParamID, "Description", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.ParamID,
                  new SelectList(Model.ProcessIDListParams, "Value", "Text"), "", new { @class = "form-control", id = "ProcessParam" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.ParamID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="forList">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.CodeValue, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.CodeValue,
            new SelectList(Model.PPvalues, "Value", "Text"), "", new { @class = "form-control", id = "PPValue" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.CodeValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="forOtherType">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.CodeValue, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.CodeValue, new { @class = "form-control", id = "PPValTextBox" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.CodeValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div id="idTypeValue1"></div>
        </div>
        @Html.Label("<=", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1", id = "SecondValueLabel" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.SecondValue, new { @class = "form-control", id = "SecondValue" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.SecondValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div id="idTypeValue2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

by calling `@Html.Action("Create", "Search")`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h5 class="modal-title">Add Parameter</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Action("Create", "Search")
            <div id="myModalContent"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" id="bntSubmit" , name="name" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far so good, my dialog opens and shows the view.

[image]

But when I click on Save button , my ajax request fails for I cannot pass the data even if I serialized the form. The form id is "form-create" on the View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new { @class = "form-control", id="form-create"  }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "wrapperViews" }))
```

but when result from serialize() is empty.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bntSubmit').click(function (e) {
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $("#form-create").serialize();
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Search/Create',
            data: form,
            success: function () {
                $('#myModal').modal("hide");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });

    });

});
```

I tried to change id form with modal id but nothing changed.
I am struggling over this for one day and no solution yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the jquery code : `data: form`     where is this form?

Comment: var form = $("#form-create").serialize(); Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you include the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" in your layout, "Ajax.Beginform" won't work without it.

If that doesn't work, try just submit the form.
By using an "Ajax.Beginform", you should just bind :

```
$(function () {
    $('#bntSubmit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form-create').submit();
    });
});
```

And use "OnSuccess" event in the "AjaxOptions" object to do the rest.

Comment: jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js is already included. Anyway I figured it out. The error was in the using. I changed that to this one: @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "wrapperViews" }, new { id = "form-create" })). in the previous one the declaration wasn't correct. Now it works. Thanks again.